# justify-self: end; не выравнивает флекс-блок по правому краю row flex-контейнера

Tags: flexbox

Не могли бы вы бросить взгляд, и помочь понять, почему
div class="button" не хочет расположиться справого края по горизонтали?
а вместо этого прилепились друг к другу и висят в центре?
И, возможно, вы знаете как этого достичь?

https://jsfiddle.net/pkqjw0d1/4/

```
<body>
   <header>
      <div class="h1">Заголовок страницы</div>
      <div class="button">Блок-кнопка</div>
   </header>

   <div class="mainArea"></div>
</body>

    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
            }
     header {    
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            position: fixed; /*КРИТИЧНО!*/
            width: 100%;
            height: 6em;
            margin-bottom: 0.5em;     
            border-bottom: 1px solid #a08a4a;
            background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 253, 210), rgba(250, 161, 32));
            box-shadow: 0 0.1em 0.2em 0.1em #716b5a;
            }

               .h1 {
                  font-size: 3em;
                  text-align: center;
               }

               .button {
                  justify-self: end;
                  width: 10%;
                  height: 3em;
                  padding: 2px;
                  border: 1px solid #000;
                  text-align: center;
                  font-size: 1em;
               }

    .mainArea {
         display: flex;
         margin-top: 6em;
                }
```

Comment: Пробовал justify-content: flex-end; для .header
Тогда оба блока выравниваются справа, но всё равно не получается их разлепить и задать каждому отдельное положение.
*...пачиму....*

Comment: Добавь flex: 1; для .h1

Comment: свойства justify-self во flexbox нету - это Вы с grid layout перепутали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во `flexbox` контейнере свойство `justify-self` игнорируется.
Эту задачу можно понять двояко: если вам надо разместить заголовок прям точнехонько в центре хедера, то `button` должен быть вне потока документа и тогда его позиционируем с помощью `position: absolute`. Если вам достаточно того, чтобы заголовок был в центре оставшейся от кнопки области, то в комментарии выше @frozencoast описал решение.

```
          .h1 {
              flex-grow: 1;
              font-size: 3em;
              text-align: center;
           }

           .button {
              width: 10%; // не очень понятно это свойство, по-моему его просто можно удалить
              height: 3em;
              padding: 2px;
              border: 1px solid #000;
              text-align: center;
              font-size: 1em;
           }
```

У родительского контейнера удаляем свойство `justify-content`.